# Request API using Reference Token in Postman

Tags: postman

I was having an issue requesting API with Reference token type, it always returns 401 but when changing to JWT it can successfully returns 200.
This is the example of the Authorization when using Reference token type:

> "Bearer B1F157A411CCF3A06C94CD1D61B892F9199CA6CFE50E2E14650FF6F23EB2A8CC-1"

Does anyone know if there is any other setting I should set to request API with Reference token type using Postman?